# DataTable Expressions And Datagrid Visibility

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datatable, expression

I was wondering is it possible to enforce a datatable expression only on 
visible columns of a datagridview.

heres a use case. 
End User has a DataGridView populated with upto ten columns of Numbers and a Final Column with a total. if the user decided to hide one of these columns (idealy) the expression would change depending on the the visible columns in the datagrid.

thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to handle the [DataGridView.ColumnStateChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnstatechanged.aspx).

In myDataTable, at first you set no Expression.
After the Grid is loaded for the first time, launch recalculateTotalExpression.

```
void recalculateTotalExpression()
{
   // 0. Create a StringBuilder for your new Expression.
   // 1. Go through each of the columns of your datagridview, except the TotalColumn
   // 2. Foreach Visible DataGridView Column, add the corresponding DataTable column to the expression.
   // 3. Set the Expression to the TotalColumn : TotalColumn.Expression = sb.toString();
}

void MyDataGridView_OnColumnStateChanged(DataGridViewColumnStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
   recalculateTotalExpression();
}
```

Comment: Thats Perfect, thanks. i was searching for a ColumnVisible Event or similar. works a charm now.